# Webcodecs mux with Ffmpeg.wasm

Tags: javascript, multiplexing, webcodecs, ffmpeg-wasm

I am currently creating a video editor with webcodecs. I would like to use FFmepg/Wasm for muxing, as I previously worked with mp4box.js and encountered many problems.

The question I have is how best to give FFMPEG the raw encoded chunks.

Unfortunately, I have never worked with WASM and FFMPEG before.

How I imagined the pipeline:

I saved all encodedChunks in arrays like:

```
encodedVideoChunks: EncodedVideoChunk[];
encodedAudioChunks: EncodedAudioChunk[];
```

A Muxer_FFmpeg class should now handle the encoded Chunks. Thats where I am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got an example of how to deal with encoded chunks on web.dev (https://web.dev/webcodecs/#encoding).

You basically copy them to a typed array and store them for later use:

```
const chunkData = new Uint8Array(chunk.byteLength);
chunk.copyTo(chunkData);
chunks.push(chunkData);
```

Muxing is a simple ffmpeg command with chunks as input. Just have to avoid reencoding with codec copy. For webm container:

```
ffmpeg -i chunks -c copy output.webm
```

For other ffmpeg common commands: https://web.dev/media-conversion/

FFmpeg.wasm FS API: https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm/blob/master/docs/api.md#ffmpeg-fs

In the case of example above, you would use fetchFile API of chunks Blob so command would be:

```
ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', 'chunks', await fetchFile(new Blob(chunks)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how can I give the encoded Chunks into the ffmpeg.wasm filesystem so that I can use them for muxing?